# Using fineuploader in node.js

Tags: node.js, fine-uploader

I have a fineuploader server set up which handles uploads from the browser using the fineuploader library. I can't seem to find anywhere if I can upload from node.js as well. Is this possible? Can I create a Blob and pass it to fineuploader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader is a browser-based upload tool. It was never designed to work server-side. If you'd like to send requests from a Node server, there are a number of library focused on that particular workflow, such as the request library.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the request npm module.